# How to write Exceptions into ULS Log using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, uls

Is there any way for logging the exceptions into ULS logs on sharepoint 2013 on-premise version? And it should be done using csom only..

Answer (score 0):

Utilize diagnostics.asmx web service -

```
SharePointDiagnostics SharePointDiagnosticsObject = new SharePointDiagnostics();
SharePointDiagnosticsObject.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
string Response = SharePointDiagnosticsObject.SendClientScriptErrorReport(message, file, line, client, stack, team, originalFile);
```

For more details on usage of diagnostics.asmx refer the following link -

https://vivekkumar11432.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/how-to-do-logging-in-uls-from-csom-in-c/